# iphone 5 media query with css

Tags: css, screen, media

**The css media screen does not work on iphone 5 has ios 7**

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {

.content_main {
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10% 5%;
    margin-top:2%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 75%;
    /*background-color: white; */

}
```

Comment: Try to give PIXELS instead of max-aspect-ratio. @media screen and (max-width:480px)

Comment: Cannot go wrong with using pixels or ems

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Any solutions?